# Explorer.exe not responding on "My Computer" access Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, freeze, black-screen-of-death

1. A little backstory

   I installed a day ago some corrupted software into my computer and soon after that I got the "black screen of death" on boot. I reinstalled my windows, erasing all partitions except one where I had some personal content, nothing related to windows or software.
2. The problem

   It all works perfectly now, except that, sometimes when I click "My Computer", the window freezes and I get the message: "Windows Explorer stopped responding".I am able to close windows.explorer after around 10 seconds, then it all works fine again, windows.explorer reloading itself after I close it. When the windows.explorer freezes, the my computer main page(the one that shows the partitions) is the ONLY one that does not respond, everything else working perfectly.
3. More details

   Note: this happens in about 50% of the cases, not everytime. PLEASE prompt me if you feel the need for more details, I just want to make it work. Also,I now have an antivirus and I ran 2 full in depth scans, finding just 2 malwares and erasing them on the first scan.
4. Full error details

> A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.
>
> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  AppHangB1   Application
>   Name: explorer.exe   Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385   Application
>   Timestamp:    4a5bc60d   Hang Signature:  f128   Hang Type:   0   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   Locale ID:   1033   Additional Hang
>   Signature 1:  f128b6859529d468288b0b438227f2a0   Additional Hang
>   Signature 2:  038d   Additional Hang Signature
>   3:    038dcc82876a0b81ae2e055408dbff7a   Additional Hang Signature
>   4:    f128   Additional Hang Signature
>   5:    f128b6859529d468288b0b438227f2a0   Additional Hang Signature
>   6:    038d   Additional Hang Signature
>   7:    038dcc82876a0b81ae2e055408dbff7a
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: How is that the same as my question?

Comment: *"I now have an antivirus and I ran 2 full in depth scans, finding just 2 malwares and erasing them on the first scan."*  I'm sorry to hear about your problems, but you can't really dismiss *"just 2 malwares"* like that.  Please take a few minutes to read the discussion in the previous question that I linked above.  Whatever method you used to alleviate your corrupted software problem still preserved the malware.  Realistically, you need to completely wipe-and-reload the computer (all partitions) using a copy of Windows obtained from a clean machine.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why the process is in a hung state you would need to analyze the threads of the process.

Two ways spring to mind.  One is quick and could give you the answer, the other is more precise.

1. Run Process Explorer, look at the threads of the Explorer.exe process. With Symbols configured, hopefully the call stacks of the threads suggest what the process is doing.  You can see here which threads are consuming the most CPU time and could be responsible.

   2. The more precise/professional way. Create a memory dump of the Explorer.exe process when it has hung and then analyse it. Most likely you will want all of the process memory when it is in the hung state. To do so, I would suggest download Procdump (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx), then in an administrative command prompt run:

procdump -h -ma explorer.exe explorer.dmp

Next time the Explore.exe process hangs, hopefully Procdump will create you a dump file to analyze.  The steps then would be to install Windbg which is part of the SDK - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk.  Just the Debugging Tools for Windows component will need to be installed.

Once installed, launch Windbg and configure symbols. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx

Then you can load the dump and run:
!analyze -hang -v

This might get you the answer as to which thread/module could be causing the issue. Maybe it points to a thread with a third-party dll on the stack that you could remove.

Generally hangs are a little more tricky than crashes as you haven't really got an error, you just have to consider what the threads are doing in context of what is going on.  Commands such as: !runaway will give you a list of threads by consumed CPU and could be a start.  I would look through each of the stacks to see if they are performing work and what modules are involved, especially if they are 3rd party, i.e. not Microsoft.

For more information on this topic see: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-172-Application-Hangs